# Using linear approximation to perform addition and subtraction | error barrier

Tags: octave, linear-regression, data-science

I'm attempting my first solo project, after taking an introductory course to machine learning, where I'm trying to use linear approximation to predict the outcome of addition/subtraction of two numbers.

I have 3 features: first number, subtraction/addition (0 or 1), and second number.
So my input looks something like this:

```
3 0 1
4 1 2
3 0 3
```

With corresponding output like this:

```
2
6
0
```

I have (I think) successfully implemented logistic regression algorithm, as the squared error does gradually decrease, but in 100 values, ranging from 0 to 50, the squared error value flattens out at around 685.6 after about 400 iterations.

[Graph: Squared Error vs Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjYCK.png)
 .

To fix this, I have tried using a larger dataset for training, getting rid of regularization, and normalizing the input values.

I know that one of the steps to fix high bias is to add complexity to the approximation,  but I want to maximize the performance at this particular level. Is it possible to go any further on this level?

My linear approximation code in Octave:

```
% Iterate
for i = 1 : iter
    % hypothesis
    h = X * Theta;

    % reg theta prep
    regTheta = Theta;
    regTheta(:, 1) = 0;

    % cost calc
    J(i, 2) = (1 / (2 * m)) * (sum((h - y) .^ 2) + lambda * sum(sum(regTheta .^ 2,1),2));

    % theta calc
    Theta = Theta -  (alpha / m) * ((h - y)' * X)' + lambda * sum(sum(regTheta, 1), 2);
end
```

Note: I'm using 0 for lambda, as to ignore regularization.

Comment: without giving complete, runnable code there is little chance that someone tries to help.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the tip! Is the code usually attached as files or text?